# Python type hinting with constraint on type superclass

Tags: python

Is it possible to add type hint in Python with constraint on the type's superclass? For example, I want something that looks like this:

```
def foo(g: T(S)) -> T:
    pass
```

which would be a function that take in a parameter `g` of type `T` and `T` must be a subclass of a class `S` or `S` itself, and the function's return value is of type `T`.

The equivalent function in C# would be something like

```
public static void foo<T>(T g) where T : S
{
}
```

I have looked in [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) but there doesn't seem to be anything about this.

Comment: Is this it? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound

Comment: @IsmailBadawi that seems to be it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound), the syntax you want seems to be:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound=S)

def foo(g: T) -> T:
    pass
```