# Python generics with restrictions?

Tags: python, python-3.8, type-hinting, mypy

Since Python 3.8 I have been able to do something like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class Stack(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Create an empty list with items of type T
        self.items: List[T] = []
```

I can may a Stack[int] or a Stack[str], T could be anything, right?

But what if I want to restrict my possible values of T to just sublasses of Foo, or things which are subclasses of Foo, and implement BarProtocol?

Scala has these nifty covariance operators:

```
T <: Foo, T <: BarProtocol
```

But is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: The best you can do is to restrict to to a list of possible types or to subtypes of some type, using the `bound` parameter of `TypeVar`, and indicate covariance/contravariance using `covariant` parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python type hinting with constraint on type superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36243112/python-type-hinting-with-constraint-on-type-superclass)